# How to document exceptions of async methods?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, documentation

A sample method with XML documentation:

```
// summary and param tags are here when you're not looking.
/// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException>
///    <paramref name="text" /> is null.
/// </exception>
public void Write(string text)
{
    if (text == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("text", "Text must not be null.");

    // sync stuff...
}
```

`Write(null)` throws an exception as expected. Here is an asynchronous method:

```
public async Task WriteAsync(string text)
{
    if (text == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("text", "Text must not be null.");

    // async stuff...
}
```

`WriteAsync(null)`, won't throw an exception until awaited. Should I specify the `ArgumentNullException` in an `exception` tag anyway? I think it would make the consumer think that calling `WriteAsync` may throw an `ArgumentNullException` and write something like this:

```
Task t;
try
{
    t = foo.WriteAsync(text);
}
catch (ArgumentNullException)
{
    // handling stuff.
}
```

What is the best practice for documenting exceptions in asynchronous methods?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not a *direct* answer, but personally I'd advise leaning towards fast-fail here; this might mean writing 2 methods:

```
public Task WriteAsync(string text) // no "async"
{
    // validation
    if (text == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("text", "Text must not be null.");

    return WriteAsyncImpl(text);
}
private async Task WriteAsyncImpl(string text)
{
    // async stuff...
}
```

This pattern is also an ideal place to add "fast path" code, for example:

```
public Task WriteAsync(string text) // no "async"
{
    // validation
    if (text == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("text", "Text must not be null.");

    if (some condition)
        return Task.FromResult(0); // or similar; also returning a pre-existing
                                   // Task instance can be useful

    return WriteAsyncImpl(text);
}
```

Comment: +1 And a longer explanation is in Jon Skeet's blog: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/11/01/control-flow-redux-exceptions-in-asynchronous-code.aspx

Comment: +1, I do that. :) But what if there are exceptions that can be thrown after awaiting, exceptions that are not related to argument validations? Should I specify them in xml documentation?

Comment: You have not addressed the point in question; i.e. how to handle the exceptions...

Comment: @ŞafakGür fortunately, C# does not have checked exceptions :) Unfortunately there is no one single answer here, because it is deferred. Without an "obvious" answer, it is largely an opinion question. Perhaps mention them but clarify that they may happen during the asynchronous operation.

Comment: @Killercam I addressed the example from the question, and I noted that it indeed may not apply to all circumstances - but (see comment immediately above) I'm not sure there *is* a single answer to that.

Comment: @LasseEspeholt link is now at https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/11/01/control-flow-redux-exceptions-in-asynchronous-code

Comment: Now with C# 8 we have static local functions, making this solution even more appealing.

Comment: I agree that this answer does not address the question. Consider people arriving here from Google who want to know how best to document exceptions from async methods. This answer does not help them.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft doesn't seem to differentiate between the `async` method throwing an exception and the returned `Task` having an exception stored in its `Exception` property.  E.g.:

[`WebClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(string, string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh159424.aspx)

Personally, I would choose to document the exceptions as part of the documentation for the return value (i.e. the returned `Task`), since the distinction may be important for clients.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise to keep the exception tags since they show up in Intellisense.

Striving for conciseness, I'd not mention whether an exception is fast failing or not, as long as this follows intuition. That is, a sanity check should fail fast, while failure during execution should not. If you must diverge from this rule, please document it.

Please be aware that changing whether the exception is thrown synchronously (fail fast) or when awaited might break customer code.

Comment: `your WriteAsync method WILL throw its ArgumentNullException just like Write does (if called from another async method, which should be the rule).` - I don't follow. Getting called from an async method doesn't magically await the resulting task, the exception can't be observed by the caller until it's awaited.

Comment: I agree on using exception tags with remarks though. The fast fail answer given by Marc can be implemented in a much prettier way since the introduction of local functions. So I use that to throw validation exceptions without involving the state machine at all. And document the others -that won't be thrown until awaited- in the exception tag just like you advise.

Comment: @ŞafakGür I was wrong, completely wrong, due to insufficient debugging. Sorry about that. This should have been downvoted. I've removed the crap and refined my opinion, while keeping my main advise.